# How does python recognize the type of argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to define a function that returns the minimum element of a list.
So I'd defined a 'minOfList' function as below:

```
def minOfList(a_list):
n = len(a_list)
x = a_list[0]
for i in range(n):
    if a_list[i] <= x:
        x = a_list[i]
    else:
        x = x
return x
```

First I set a list and put that into the above function.

```
x = [1, 1, 5, 6, 9, 5, 4, 5]
minOfList(x)
```

Then I redefined x as a tuple and feed x into the function.

```
x = (1, 1, 5, 6, 9, 5, 4, 5)
minOfList(x)
```

Whether I define x as a list or a tuple, the function worked well.

Question:
How does python know exactly which data type of the argument is fed into the function? Additionally, I'd like know a way to designate data type of the argument when I define a function?

Comment: It doesn't know, it tries it to see if it works.

Comment: I would like to ask if you know any other programming languages as yopu don't seem to be following the Python way of doing things in the example above. Maybe you need to first follow the Python tutorial available from the Python web site, as some of your issues may be down to how you approach Python, and that tutorial will show you the right approach. – Paddy3118 1 min ago   edit

Comment: @Paddy3118 No I don’t really use any other languages now. As you said Im reading tutorials about control flow and defining functions. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @TaeChoi; If the tutorial you are following is pointing you to create the above code for going through all items in a list then It might work, but they are not teaching you true Python skills. You need to look for another, better, tutorial that would teach you how to avoid getting the len() of a list then using range in a for loop to index a lists items explicitly. You can directly iterate over the items of a list. If you do need the index, (and half the time you don't), You can use enumerate(). The standard Python tutorial would have that, as would many others. :-)

Comment: @Paddy3118 Thank you very much. I am following 'Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures using Python, By Brad Miller and David Ranum, Luther College'. The cod i made was not what they pointed me to make. But I made those code for myself as a self check. I'm only a beginner so my code must be poor now. I'm looking forward to enhance my skills. And I also checks the standard python tutorial you mentioned for me, too. Thanks again really.

Comment: @TaeChoi, It is good that you are exploring like this. It will make it easier to compare and contrast the more Pythonic solution when come across them. I hope you have fun with Python! As I have :-)  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't use static type-casting. So the short answer is No, Python doesn't know what type of variable is being passed into your function.

There is a way to check manually however, using the isinstance() function.

isinstance(your_var, type); returns True or False.

Here is an example that relates to the function you are building.

```
if isinstance(a_list, list) or isinstance(a_list, tuple):
     Your code
else:
     Return bad var type
```

In addition, there is a way to recommend to the user the type of the variable the function expects to take, using this syntax:

```
def minOfList(a_list: list):
     return
```

This lets the user know what type they should be passing in. Be cautioned however, this does not force the parameter type - the use can still pass in any variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh your answer really helped me. Thanks. I didn't think about using **isinstance** function. I also didn't know at all that I could recommend to the user about the type of the variable the function expects. Thanks again.

Comment: depending on the philosophy, you should avoid heavy use of is `isinstance`. As you see above your code works perfectly, without checking for `isinstance`. This is called [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) which is often used  in python

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Very true - but there are times when you need to do a manual check, or run different code based on a variable type. I would rather use isinstance() than a try/catch block.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use a decorator together with annotations:

```
def check_type(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs): 
        for name, t in f.__annotations__.items(): 
            if not isinstance(kwargs[name], t):
                raise TypeError("Incorrect argument type!") 
        return f(*args, **kwargs) 
    return decorated

@check_type # Use it before any function on which you want to check argument type
def foo(bar: str):
    print(bar)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don' t really understand the check_type function and the @check_type state because of my poor understanding. But I expect to learn a lot as I search those things. Thank you.

Comment: search for decorators in python, pretty useful and pythonic to me :)

Comment: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) Searching how and when to use *args and *kwargs now. And gonna search for decorators just now. I found them really interesting! Thanks again.